# Integrate chi-square-tests in meta-analysis

Tags: chi-squared-test, meta-analysis, effect-size

I would like to do a meta-analysis, based on community-based intervention studies. In the studies the chi-squares and the p-values are given. But the sample size is related to entire cities, so I don't have specific groups. How do I get effect sizes and especially confidence intervals and standard errors?
And can I use the total observations as "n" or is it always the total sample size?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the result of a single primary study looks like by editing. There are many ways that a value of chi-squared can arise.

Comment: Yes, of course i try. They tested whether the number of suicides in the intervention region differed from the number in the control region within 2 years. There is a 2x2 table with the suicides for the baseline and the intervention year.

Comment: Have you thought of computing the odds ratio or risk ratio (on the log scale) with its standard error? That would be sufficient for meta-analysis unless you have something else in mind.

Comment: I thought about it, but i was not sure, if this is possible without  "real" sample sizes. What do you think? Thank you.

Comment: Are the sample sizes not implicit in the 2 by 2 table?

Comment: No unfortunately that there are no "real groups", but the suicides in the two cities (control and intervention) have been counted year by year. And these were then statistically compared in chi-square-tests